# Sorting problem in document library sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When sorting by name in a SharePoint 2010 library, numeric results are sorting incorrectly. For instance "122_Test" will sort in front of "13_Test". I know at one point years ago Windows Explorer had the same issue, but when viewing the same library by using the Open with Explorer option, Windows Explorer correctly displays the results.how to reslove this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to fix it is to create a number column and set the number there then sort by the number field and it should work. It is doing a text sort and 122 comes before 13, that's the way Sharepoint has been for as long as I can remember, my earliest experience is with the 2003 version.